# Is the reciprocal of the second derivative equal to the inverse function of second derivative?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Problem statement:

y=f(x)

We know that dy/dx = 1/(dx/dy)

Does the second derivative of y equal the reciprocal of the second derivative of x?
And if so, how would you prove this?

Comment: Have you tried any examples?  What about $y=x$, say?  Or $y=x^2$ for $x>0$, say?

Comment: Theyre clearly not the same. Thank you !

Comment: And not that $\frac{dy}{dx}=1/\frac{dx}{dy}$ holds in general.